# VIM Search and Replace - the Reference

Tags: vim

VIM search and replace command to find the `);` - *end of method* string and replace with the an additional parameter for the lines that starts with `strlcpy` function.

**Input**

```
strlcpy(p->account,gettoken(NULL,&plast));      //Set Account Information
strlcpy(p->startDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),'0')); /* YYYYMMDD */
strlcpy(p->status,gettoken(NULL,&plast));
```

**Expected Output** (Copy the first parameter i.e `p->account` and replace the `);` with `sizeof(p->account));`

```
strlcpy(p->account,gettoken(NULL,&plast),sizeof(p->account));     //Set Account Information
strlcpy(p->startDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),'0'),sizeof(p->startDate)); /* YYYYMMDD */
strlcpy(p->status,gettoken(NULL,&plast),sizeof(p->status));
```

Eg. Following command that search and replaces the );

```
:g/strlcpy(/s/);/,sizeof());/g
```

with

```
 strlcpy(p->balance,getInfo(NULL,&account),sizeof());
```

How to pass the `p->balance` as an argument to the `sizeof()` ?

Appreciate the earliest reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:%s/strlcpy(\(.\{-}\),.*\zs);/, sizeof(\1));`

Here is what is is broken down:

- `%` for all the lines
- `s` substitute
- `/` start the search pattern
- `strlcpy(` match `strlcpy(`
- `\(` start a match group to capture the contents to use later
- `.\{-}` match all the characters using the non-greedy multiplier `\{-}`
- `\)` finish the match group
- `,` force matching a comma. Combined with the non-greedy `\{-}` this has the effect of selecting until before the first comma
- `.*` match all the characters
- `\zs` make the substitution start after this point
- `);` match `);`
- `/` start the substitution portion of the command
- `, sizeof(` substitute after `\zs` with `, sizeof(`
- `\1` use the contents of the previous match group in the replacement
- `));` complete the substitution with `));`

Answer (score 1):

**Input:**

```
strlcpy(p->account,gettoken(NULL,&plast));      //Set Account Information
strlcpy(p->startDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),'0')); /* YYYYMMDD */
strlcpy(p->status,gettoken(NULL,&plast));
```

**Command:**

```
:%s/\(strlcpy(p->\)\([0-9A-Za-z]*\)\(\,.*))\)/\1\2\3,sizeof(p->\2))/g
```

**Output:**

```
strlcpy(p->account,gettoken(NULL,&plast)),sizeof(p->account));      //Set Account Information
strlcpy(p->startDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),'0')),sizeof(p->startDate)); /* YYYYMMDD */
strlcpy(p->status,gettoken(NULL,&plast)),sizeof(p->status));
```

**NOTE:**

Command is ran inside of vim!